# Having some trouble with android studio probably has a simple answer

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, emulation, hypervisor

I'm trying to install android studio, but while I was installing it I got this exception:

[image]

My question is what is the Android Emulator Hypervisor? what does it do or enable me to do? I tried looking it up online but I kept getting into these rabbit holes of information that kept expanding and expanding. I just want a concise answer for my small brain and maybe a quick and clear explanation to fix this.

Comment: From the Google definition - "**Hypervisor** - a program used to run and manage one or more virtual machines on a computer." It's used for emulating android devices.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator essentially creates virtual machines running specific Android versions in order to run your apps. The Hypervisor driver is something that can help a lot with performance. If you want to check out the details, this [documentation page](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#vm-windows) might be a good start.

To fix your installation issue you only need to follow the link given in your error message, there's not much need to understand hypervisor workings.